# Use mousePressed() function in p5js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, p5.js

```
//stroke weight
let strokeweight_driver = sin(millis()/300)
stroke_weight = map((strokeweight_driver), -1, 1, 5, 8)
stroke("black")
strokeweight(stroke_weight)
circle(20,30,20)
```

I want to make this strokeweight of circle in 20, when I click the screen.
So I decided to use a mousePressed function and type a stroke_weight = 20 but it doesn't work.
What should I do?
p.s. English is not my mother language so there're might be has a wrong sentence. Please understand me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no strokeweight() function. It's strokeWeight().
Try this:

````
stroke_weight = map((strokeweight_driver), -1, 1, 5, 8)
stroke("black")
strokeWeight(stroke_weight)
circle(20,30,20)```
````